# toggle between multiple colors, with javascript

Tags: javascript, toggle

Trying to make a function that toggles through classes of different background colors when you click on "r". If its green, it goes yellow, if its yellow it goes red etc.. But i'm not really getting it to work. Whats the best approach to achieve this?

Tried something like this:

```
  var shape1 = document.getElementById("shape1");

  //toggle between colors on keydown "r".
  function changeColor (event) {
  var key = event.keyCode;

     if (key === 82 && shape1.className.match(/(?:^|\s)green(?!\S)/)) {
        shape1.classList.toggle('yellow');
     }
     if (key === 82 && shape1.className.match(/(?:^|\s)yellow(?!\S)/)) {
        shape1.classList.toggle('red');
     }
     if (key === 82 && shape1.className.match(/(?:^|\s)red(?!\S)/)) {
        shape1.classList.toggle('blue');
     }
     if (key === 82 && shape1.className.match(/(?:^|\s)blue(?!\S)/)) {
        shape1.classList.toggle('green');
     }
  }
  document.addEventListener("keydown", changeColor, false);
```

But yeah.. its not really working out. Suppose toggle isn't the right way of doing it.
jsfiddle for demonstration:
https://jsfiddle.net/rbf10qjn/

Comment: well you probably need to remove the old ones and since you are using classList, why are you not using contains()?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly get rid of the first line which confuses the interpreter by creating a variable with exactly the same name as the ID. What was that for?

```
var shape1 = document.getElementById("shape1");
```

Since you know the name just use the ID directly!

Second, your approach is wrong. Instead of addEventListener use a method like this...

```
document.onkeydown=function(e){

if ((e.keyCode===82) && (shape1.style.backgroundColor=='green')) {shape1.style.backgroundColor='yellow';} else
if ((e.keyCode===82) && (shape1.style.backgroundColor=='yellow')) {shape1.style.backgroundColor='red';} else
if ((e.keyCode===82) && (shape1.style.backgroundColor=='red')) {shape1.style.backgroundColor='blue';}

etc... etc

}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Thanks.
Though I'm still not sure how the if-statements should be like.

Comment: I've edited the above to cycle through colors. I hope its ok.

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't seem to work. Check https://jsfiddle.net/o5ct1r6a/1/

Comment: When you fetch a color from the browser for a test/comparison (==) it’s not returned as “black” or “#000000” but this format… “rbg(0,0,0)” unfortunately, so that may be why it’s not working.